# Is the File pointer causing segmentation fault in code

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

char date[35] = {"0"};

void main()
{
        FILE *fp;
        char ch;
        int i=0;

        if(fork() == 0)
        {
                system("date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' > date.txt");
                exit(0);
        }
        wait(0);

        fp = fopen("date.txt","w+");
        if(fp == 0) {return;}

        while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
        {
                date[i++] = (char)ch;
        }
        fclose(fp);
        date[i] = '\0';

        printf("date = %s", date);
}
```

I keep on getting segmentation fault in this code.
I have even tried creating the file named "date.txt" manually.

The command `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' > date.txt` works on bash separately well.

Can someone please help me find, what am I doing wrong?

[update:] Forgot to initialize i = 0. Edited but still the segment violation persists.

Comment: You should be checking if fp is == to NULL, not 0

Comment: Here `date[i++]` what is `i` value ? you didn't initialize `i`.

Comment: .. `int i = 0;`

Comment: Getting segmentation fault either way .@Jǝssǝ

Comment: Thanks. I have now initiliazed `i =0` . Still I get the segment violation @

Comment: Also if you open file in `w+` mode, what this `fgetc(fp))` will store into `date` ? Nothing. Bcz `w+` means first it will truncate old data and then  write/read.

Comment: 'char ch;' will never be EOF.

Comment: @MartinJames Thank you. It works now.

Comment: If changing char to int solved your problem, you can mark the answer as correct by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons. (This will also give you two reputation points)

Answer (score 1):

You are using a char value to check against EOF, but since EOF is a numeric value, ch will never be equal to EOF. This means that your loop will run forever, overrunning your array, which only has 35 elements. You have to use `int ch` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should to initial variable `i` or it gets a random value.

```
void main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Stupid mistake. I initialized i = 0. However, the segment violation is still persisting

Comment: I dont get any segfault, try to provide example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

The statement overflowed the max size of 35. That means `i` become greater than 0..34.

```
date[i++] = (char)ch;
```